# Dissolve Multisite while making site #5 the main site?

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I have a very unique situation, I was also unable to find a solution, but perhaps someone else has experienced something like this before.

A client of mine has a multisite set up, however they now want to dissolve the network. My dilemma? Site #5 on the network is now the main site and needs to become the only site and remain on the current domain.

I've tried removing multisite (per this tut. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/uninstall-multisite/) but it didn't seem to work. What happened was site #1 became the main site and site #5 was no longer available. Since then I've undone everything in the tutorial.

I'm sure I've left out some important info, so if you need more details, kindly let me know! :)

Comment: What kind of multisite do you have?

Comment: My multisite is rusty, but I think you'd need to rename the wp_* tables so that the tables for blog 5 (check the ID in the wp_blogs table) are the 'normal' prefix. That might be as simple as changing the `$table_prefix` in wp-config to be `wp_5_` but I think there are global tables too (e.g. wp_users?) that don't have a numbered prefix version: your best bet might be to 1) backup your DB! 2) rename any unnumbered wp_* table that has a wp_5_* equivalent out of the way 3) rename the wp_5_* tables to wp_* only.

Comment: @TomJNowell Are there different types? Everything is it's own domain, if that's what you mean, it's not a community.

Comment: @Rup Thank you, I'll make sure to try this, hopefully it produces the results I'm after!

Comment: You mean you have a subdomain install, not a subdirectory install?